# What would the surface temperature of the Earth be without the Sun?

Tags: temperature, earth, estimation, planets, heat-conduction

If the Sun would not heat the earth, and never had heated it in the past,
its surface would only be heated from the inside.

What would be the current temperature of the surface?

Comment: Perhaps better over on Earth Sciences?

Comment: And answered there: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/9210/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the current equilibrium surface temperature of Earth, i.e. without the sun?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/9210/)

Comment: One could say that without the sun ever heating the earth (meaning no sun), we would not have the earth....

Answer (score -4):

57 degrees Fahrenheit

And without sunlight, the Earth would get very, very cold. Earth's surface temperature now averages about 57 degrees Fahrenheit, but by the end of the first week without the sun, the average surface temperature would be below the freezing point.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. If $57^{\circ} F$ is the temperature with the sun, how much will it be without it